# how to add matplotlib axis unit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i * 2872155 for i in range(1, 11)]
y = [0.219, 0.402,  0.543,  0.646,0.765,  0.880,1.169, 1.358,1.492,1.611]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

and the plot is

[image]

But I want the y label to be like 0.2s, 0.4s, 0.6s.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can add Y axis level by `plt.ylabel("In Seconds")`.

Comment: I don't agree that this should be considered a duplicate. The answer to the question depends on what you want to have as a unit for the axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker  
x = [i * 2872155 for i in range(1, 11)]
y = [0.219, 0.402,  0.543,  0.646,0.765,  0.880,1.169, 1.358,1.492,1.611]

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f s'))
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3):

Or use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
x = [i * 2872155 for i in range(1, 11)]
y = [0.219, 0.402,  0.543,  0.646,0.765,  0.880,1.169, 1.358,1.492,1.611]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1fs'))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use type conversion if you just want to add 's' to y values

```
x = [i * 2872155 for i in range(1, 11)]
y = [0.219, 0.402, 0.543,  0.646,0.765,  0.880,1.169, 1.358,1.492,1.611]
z = [str(i)+'s' for i in y]
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.show()
```